# Is there a way to grab a text without using component props in Svelte

Tags: svelte

So, I'm just trying to make a simple button component for myself. Then I want to add a Label component to label the Button. Is there a way to grab the text inside the Component tags like this and then passing it along as a variable?

```
<Button>
    <Label>Is there a way to grab this text?</Label>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need [slots](https://svelte.dev/docs#slot).

With a slot, you can define your `Label` like this:

`Label.svelte`

```
<label>
  <slot />
</label>
```

... and use it like in your example:

```
<script>
  import Label from './Label.svelte'
</script>

<Label>Some text</Label>
```

You can't directly access the slot's content through a variable, though.

If you really need it in a variable, then you'll need to resort to some trickery. Something like having a `bind:this={el}` on a DOM *element* (not component), and use normal DOM API to read the content (e.g. `el.innerHTML`, `el.textContent`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. I just remembered that Slots exist.